# When I press up-arrow in 'less' in mintty (cygwin), only the top line changes. How do I fix this?

Tags: cygwin, less, mintty

Here is what is happening:

[image: Demo of problem]

How do I fix this?

(Just to be clear, the issue occurs when I type `less <any filename>`.  The `man less` in the gif is just an arbitrary command to demonstrate the visual behavior of my `less` command.

Answer (score 0):

I was on an old version, MinTTY 2.9.2.  Updating to the latest version fixed it.